# Always get at approval workflow reject status

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I prepered a workflow in Sharepoint Designer. 
Only with one line of code:

[image]

But when I start the workflow I always get Rejected status - I don't know why:
[image]
[image]

Please Help. What should I do to get something to chooseto set status of workflow.

On English it looks like this, but it is Sharepoint 2013:

[image]

Comment: If someone give -1 should say why He gives -1 mark.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot with English version?

Comment: How could I change this ?

Comment: Please check below link
https://olafd.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/switch-language-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: But I showing the screen on Designer.

Comment: Yes for while you can change language and take screenshot then revert back your changes.

Comment: Have you done changes in CertificationApproval process?

Comment: No i nothing change

Comment: I changed before. But I deleted, and start again

Comment: Refer SharePoint logs to get actual error.

Comment: I think it is not error. I think its why in workflow it has got reject status

Comment: When I remove set reject status. I get Commpleted, so the workflow goes to completed section.